# how to view CString object value in debug in VC6 environment

Tags: visual-c++-6

In VC 6 environment what is the settings to be done to view the value of the CString in debug mode. Even in watch window ??? appears for CString variables!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have proper Debug symbols? . pdb may be outdated

Answer (score 0):

try using the GetBuffer method in the watch window.

```
cStringVariable.GetBuffer()
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue as OP, and when I try cStringVariable.GetBuffer() in the watch window, I'm told the overload with this parameter count does not exist.  I then try cStringVariable.GetBuffer(20) and get "member function not present".

Answer (score 0):

Try using XDebug plugin for VC6. Look [here](http://humanier.blogspot.com/2010/06/viewing-strings-in-visual-studio-6.html)

Comment: I tried installing this add-in, but I get an error when VC6 loads the DLL: "Unable to register this add-in because its DllRegisterServer returns an error."

Comment: Follow-up, I was able to install the add-in (must run VC6 as administrator). However, XDebug doesn't work with unicode strings.